# How to remove orange dots in Ubuntu Dock

Tags: gnome-shell, dock, ubuntu-dock

Is it possible to remove the little orange dots on Ubuntu Dock next to the application-icon?

[image: sample of orange dots]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock custom-theme-running-dots 'false'
```

Comment: thanks, now i have lines (i like them more then the dots), but is it also possible to remove any information other than the icon of the application, in all my cases i move my mouse to the dock, i'm gonne klick on the icon, i don't really care if it was open before or not.

Comment: @yellowsir Sounds like a different issue. Perhaps you should ask a new question with current screenshot(s).

Comment: if you have asked this question somewhere else and someone gave you the true answer, can you share the link here? thanks!

Comment: @cduguet i gave up, i do not even know what they should represent.